# Trouble loading the JSON extended parser after Rails 3.1 -> 3.2 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm upgrading a Rails app from 3.1.10 to 3.2.11. I'm using version 1.7.6 of the json gem.

At the top of my app controller I had been requiring the library like this: `require 'json/ext'`, enforcing the use of the extended json parser.

After the upgrade, this line throws an error: "no such file to load -- json/ext/parser".

Everything works fine if I use the pure parser, either by changing the requirement to `require 'json'` or `require json/pure`.

The [documentation](http://flori.github.com/json/) recommends using the extended parser if possible, citing performance advantages. I'm looking for help getting the extended variant to work. Thanks!